# Zoom on an image on mouse move: reaching all corners

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, aspect-ratio, zooming

I'm working on a zoom functionality. This zoom is a fixed box with 100% of the window size and inside an image with the 200% of the width of the fixed box.

This zoom needs to work like this:

- When the cursor is in the center of the window, the image should be in the center.
- When the cursor is in the top right corner, the image should stay at the top right corner of the window (so reach the image with the corner)
- When the cursor is in the middle bottom corner, the image should center horizontally and reach the total bottom, so we can see the middle bottom part of the image.
- And so on.

I make an approachment, but I can't reach the corners perfectly. This is my snippet (see the comments in onmousemove function):

```js
var Zoom = function(imageZoom) {
  this.urlImage = imageZoom;
  this.img = undefined;
  this.$img = undefined;

  this.init = function() {
    this.loaders("on");
    this.calcs();
  };
  this.calcs = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.onload = function() {
      self.build();
    };
    this.img.src = this.urlImage;
  };
  this.loaders = function(status) {
    switch(status) {
      case "on":
        $('#loader').fadeIn(200);
        break;
      case "off":
        $('#loader').fadeOut(200);
        break;
    }
  };
  this.build = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$img = $(self.img);
    
    $('#zoom').fadeIn(200).append(this.$img);
    
    this.$img.on('mousedown', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
    
    // this is the problematic function
    $('body').on('mousemove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // calc the percents of the window where
      var px = 100 * e.pageX / $(window).width(); 
      var py = 100 * e.pageY / $(window).height();

      // calc of the percent pixel of the image
      var fx = self.$img.width() * px / 100;
      var fy = self.$img.height() * py / 100;

      // render it left / 2 and top / 1.5 (the 1.5 value is imaginary!!)
      self.$img.css({'transform': 'translate('+ -(fx/2) +'px, '+ -(fy/1.5)+'px)'});
    });
    self.loaders("off");
  };
};

var zoom = new Zoom("http://dummyimage.com/2000x1230/000/fff");
zoom.init();
```

```css
#zoom {
 position: fixed;;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 1000000;
 display: none;
}
#zoom img {
 width: 200%;
 height: auto;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: crosshair;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader">Loading</div>
<div id="zoom"></div>
```

The problem is that I put the `fx/1.5` because  `fx/2` doesn't work. But the horizontal value works perfecly.

What value can I config to reach all corners? Why the left value (division of the pixels by 2) works perfectly when the top value doesn't?

Comment: If I'm not missing something, as the viewport is not a square you'd might need to calc its aspect ratio. Also, wouldn't `translate` be better to use?

Comment: I try in first instance translate, but with some changes my final code looks as this! LOL

Comment: Well, I change it again to `translate()`, but obviously that's not the problem. How can I implement aspect ratio here, @LGSon ?

Comment: I will take a look a little bit later, don't have time right now ... let you know when done

Comment: No problem, I have no hurry with this task, only I'm stucked. Thank you ;)

Comment: As you can see, I posted an answer but had to delete it temporary, as I forgot to also compensate for the image's aspect ratio. It will take more time for me as I am a little busy right now. If you check my notes I added after I deleted it, you'll see where I am going with this.

Comment: I was playing with aspects ratio but with poor results. I appreciate your help. You can assume that images will be at 1:1 escale, (e.g.1000×1000), but it's better if we don't make any assumptions about the image dimensions. Thank you.

Comment: @LGSon no more news about this? :(

Comment: I were gone from here from Aug 2 until last week, so I'm glad you got some answers. Wasn't expecting it to take that long time.

Comment: Don't worry @LGSon , it's fine, however if you have a better solution than the accepted answer you'll get the bounty. Accepted answer is fine but not perfect, some horizontal positions can't be reached never. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were really close. You just need to calculate for `image.height - window.height` when getting vertical percentage.

**This will also work with different image aspect ratios**, since it takes image height into account when making calculations. Width is a non-issue since it is always double the window width.

```js
var Zoom = function(imageZoom) {
  this.urlImage = imageZoom;
  this.img = undefined;
  this.$img = undefined;

  this.init = function() {
    this.loaders("on");
    this.calcs();
  };
  this.calcs = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.onload = function() {
      self.build();
    };
    this.img.src = this.urlImage;
  };
  this.loaders = function(status) {
    switch (status) {
      case "on":
        $('#loader').fadeIn(200);
        break;
      case "off":
        $('#loader').fadeOut(200);
        break;
    }
  };
  this.build = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$img = $(self.img);

    $('#zoom').fadeIn(200).append(this.$img);

    this.$img.on('mousedown', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    // this is the problematic function
    $('body').on('mousemove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var wx = $(window).width();
      var wy = $(window).height();
      var iy = self.$img.height();

      var px = e.pageX;
      var py = e.pageY;

      var tx = -1 * (px / wx) * wx;
      var ty = -1 * (py / wy) * (iy - wy);

      self.$img.css({
        'transform': 'translate(' + tx + 'px, ' + ty + 'px)'
      });
    });
    self.loaders("off");
  };
};

var zoom = new Zoom("http://dummyimage.com/2000x1200/000/fff");
zoom.init();
```

```css
#zoom {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000000;
  display: none;
}
#zoom img {
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: crosshair;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader">Loading</div>
<div id="zoom"></div>
```

*As a bonus:*

If you want to get rid of the empty space left when aspect ratio of the image is high ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozzan/6f53j6hx/1/)), you can make sure the image height is at least equal to window height ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozzan/6f53j6hx/3/)). But, you will need to set `width: auto` in this case, so image will not always be twice as wide as window.

Comment: I need to make some test, but that's really fine. My upvote while I implement it.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, I changed the image in the snippet and it seems fine. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: In the snippet all is perfect, in my implementation (I copy exactly your calculations) the right side is not reached totally, and the image I share with you have a wide right side, so it's very annoying to user can't reach the right side of the image. I will test again when I arrive home, and probably this is the answer with the bounty. Maybe my code is making conflicts. Thank you again!

Comment: If you can share your test code with problems I can take a look at it to try and see what seems to be the problem. The width calculations in the code is not as specific as it could be, it's simplified since images's width is always assumed to be double of the window's.

Comment: Yeah, that premise is correct, the image always will be `200%` of the parent width, so the variable unknown size is the height. Right now I can't share the URL with you, maybe in an hour or two I can give you the URL to test it. Thank you again.

Comment: Ok, finally I get it working but I need to compensate some incongruences with a `'left': '-5%',` I don't know why the right side is not reaching totally. However, this a valid answer. You'll get the bounty ;) Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Just making a guess: If you have other elements in your live example, (I am assuming you do since you are having problems not present in the snippet), the problem might be caused by box-sizing and/or padding/margin values set to some other elements affecting the image's placing.

Comment: No, box sizing is set to border-box in all the page :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve what you want with CSS modification. If you try to use clip, transform translate and transform scale together in onmousemove event, you can shift the image as specified in your question. Please let me know, if this is desired behavior, thank you.

```js
var divPos = {left:0,top:0};
var offset = $("#loader").offset();
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
  divPos = {
    left: e.pageX - offset.left,
    top: e.pageY - offset.top
  };

  console.log("x:" + divPos.left + " y: " + divPos.top);
});

var Zoom = function(imageZoom) {
  this.urlImage = imageZoom;
  this.img = undefined;
  this.$img = undefined;

  this.init = function() {
    this.loaders("on");
    this.calcs();
  };
  
  this.calcs = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.onload = function() {
      self.build();
    };
  
    this.img.src = this.urlImage;
  };
  this.loaders = function(status) {
    switch(status) {
      case "on":
        $('#loader').fadeIn(200);
        break;
      case "off":
        $('#loader').fadeOut(200);
        break;
    }
  };
  this.build = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$img = $(self.img);
                
    $('#zoom').fadeIn(200).append(this.$img);
                
    this.$img.on('mousedown', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });

                
    // this is the problematic function
    $('body').on('mousemove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var width = $(self.img).width();
      var height = $(self.img).height();
      // img center calculation
      var imgCenterX = width/2;
      var imgCenterY = height/2;
      // translate calculation
      var tx = imgCenterX-divPos.left;
      var ty = imgCenterY-divPos.top;

      // clip calculation
      var c0 = divPos.top/2;
      var c1 = divPos.left/2 + width/2;
      var c2 = divPos.top/2 + height/2;
      var c3 = divPos.left/2;

      console.log(c0 + ',' + c1 + ',' + c2 + ',' + c3);

      var t = 'translate('+ tx +'px, '+ ty +'px)';
      var c = 'rect('+ c0 +'px,'+ c1 +'px,'+ c2 +'px,'+ c3 +'px)';
      self.$img.css({'transform': t + ' scale(2,2)'});
      self.$img.css({'clip': c});
    });
    self.loaders("off");
  };
};

var zoom = new Zoom("http://dummyimage.com/2000x1230/000/fff");
zoom.init();
```

```css
#zoom {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 1000000;
            display: none;
}
#zoom img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            cursor: crosshair;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader">Loading</div>
<div id="zoom"></div>
```

Comment: Hum, seems a great idea but it doesn't work properly, at least in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wznpL539/ with a touch device. Top, left and bottom works fine, when right side is not. Thank you. I give you an upvote because your fantastic way to do this.

Comment: Please, try to use stacksnippets like I do in the question, you must click in the icon of code snippet in the top of the editor. You can add javascript, css and html codes splitted in the three windows with fourth for the preview. When it's ok, save to the post, and all of us will be able to reproduce the code.

Comment: I will try to update my answer, thanks for telling, I am new here :). In the meantime, please check https://jsfiddle.net/wznpL539/1/

Comment: I think now it works as you wanted. The only problem now is deformation of the image caused by different aspect ratio of div and image.

Comment: If you can see, in low resolutions of the viewport, the image doesn't reach more than the half of itself. In high resolutions works fine,but my code works in the same way, my code works in high resolutions but bad in height in low resolutions.

Comment: And image height needs to be `auto` to avoid deformations